# Excel: SumIf retrieving 0 when cell is blank

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have the below formula that populates rates based on some conditions. My issue is that the formula shows a "0%" when the cells that meet these conditions are blank. I tried nesting the formula below in a IsBlank formula, but that didn't work.

```
=SUMIFS('Competitive Analysis'!$I:$I,'Competitive Analysis'!$A:$A,'Series Summary (MG)'!G$6,'Competitive Analysis'!$C:$C,"SET",'Competitive Analysis'!$D:$D,$G$3,'Competitive Analysis'!$E:$E,'Series Summary (MG)'!$G$4)
```

Comment: What would you want to happen instead ? This is the default behavior.

Comment: I prefer that it give me "-" if the cells are blank

Answer (score 0):

If you want `-` instead of zero then you can either format the cell as

```
[=0]"-"
```

or use formula as

```
=IF(SUMIFS(.....)=0,"-",SUMIFS(.....))
```

Comment: Thanks. Issue with that solution is that there are 0s in some of the cells and i want to show them if that is the case. Just want to blanks to not show up as 0.